# Counting the rows on the basis of row group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am creating a report in SSRS 2008R2. Report looks like this:

```
                      NSN         Learner          Employer      Completed Date
 Qualification 1      123356       Tom             Employer 1     12/2/2012
                      213134       Jerry           Employer 2     25/2/2010
                      545456       Harry           Employer 3     04/2/2011
 Qualification 2      565557       Pete            Employer 1     17/12/2001
                      154646       Susie           Employer 5     12/13/2005
```

I want to calculate the total number of records in one qualification and put it as a row in the table after each qualification. Table is grouped by qualification field. Report should look like this:

```
                      NSN         Learner          Employer      Completed Date
 Qualification 1      123356       Tom             Employer 1     12/2/2012
                      213134       Jerry           Employer 2     25/2/2010
                      545456       Harry           Employer 3     04/2/2011
                                                   **Total             3**
 Qualification 2      565557       Pete            Employer 1     17/12/2001
                      154646       Susie           Employer 5     12/13/2005
                                                    **Total             2**
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add total after group and use expression `CountDistinct(Completed_Date)` to get desired value